# Migrate records to another table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables which are not fully equal but similar. They look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE FIRST_TABLE(
  FIRST_ID          RAW(16)                                   NOT NULL CONSTRAINT FIRST_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  FIRST_NAME        VARCHAR2(2000),
  FIRST_VALID       NUMBER(1)                                 NOT NULL,
  AUDIT_CRE_AT      TIMESTAMP(0) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP    NOT NULL,
  AUDIT_CRE_FROM    VARCHAR2(32) DEFAULT 'system'             NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT SECOND_VALID CHECK (SECOND_VALID IN (0,1))
);

CREATE TABLE SECOND_TABLE(
  SECOND_ID          RAW(16)                                 NOT NULL CONSTRAINT SECOND_PK PRIMARY KEY,
  SECOND_NAME        VARCHAR2(2000),
  AUDIT_CRE_AT       TIMESTAMP(0) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP  NOT NULL,
  AUDIT_CRE_FROM     VARCHAR2(32) DEFAULT 'system'           NOT NULL,
);
```

Now I want to migrate all records from the `FIRST_TABLE` into the `SECOND_TABLE` if the record is valid. A record is valid, if `FIRST_VALID` is `1`. 
That is what I want to to:

- Select all valid records from FIRST_TABLE

`SELECT *  FROM FIRST_TABLE f WHERE f.FIRST_VALID like '1';`

- Loop through all records I got from the select query and `INSERT` everything except `VALID` `INTO` the `SECOND_TABLE` and `DELETE` them.
  Thats where I got problems. This is what I have:

  ```
  DECLARE 
  v_count_valids NUMBER(10):= 0;
  v_i NUMBER(10):=0; 


  BEGIN
       SELECT COUNT(*) INTO v_count_valids FROM FIRST_TABLE f WHERE f.VALID like '1'; 
       WHILE  v_i <= v_count_valids
       LOOP
           --INSERT INTO SECOND_TABLE VALUES (current record...)
           --DELETE current record
           v_i := v_i + 1;
       END LOOP;
  END;
  ```

Can you give me a hint how I can access the current in the loop record to insert some values into the other table? Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into second_table(second_id, second_name, audit_cre_at, audit_cre_from)
    SELECT first_id, first_name, audit_cre_at, audit_cre_from
    FROM FIRST_TABLE f
    WHERE f.FIRST_VALID = 1;
```

You don't need PL/SQL for this.  Also, when comparing numbers, use numeric constants and `=`, not `like` and strings.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop. You could use an insert-select statement instead:

```
INSERT INTO second_table (second_id, second_name, audit_cre_at, audit_cre_from)
SELECT first_id, first_name, audit_cre_at, audit_cre_from
FROM   first_table
WHERE  valid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As others mentioned, no need of writing `PL/SQL` code. First, put all your specific data from `First_Table` to `Second_Table` using below query.

```
INSERT INTO SECOND_TABLE(SECOND_ID, SECOND_NAME, AUDIT_CRE_AT, AUDIT_CRE_FROM)
    SELECT FIRST_ID, FIRST_NAME, AUDIT_CRE_AT, AUDIT_CRE_FROM FROM FIRST_TABLE WHERE FIRST_VALID = 1;
```

And then, as you mentioned, you need to delete them. Then, write delete query

```
DELETE FROM FIRST_TABLE WHERE FIRST_VALID = 1;
```